# Insert New Line in StringGrid

Tags: delphi, vcl

I have a StringGrid which is able to draw new lines using an OnDraw method.

It works fine, but now I want that the user can enter a New Line using the keyboard. At the moment, multiline texts have to be copypasted into the StringGrid.

Everytime VK_RETURN is pressed, the StringGrid leaves the Edit mode. What do I have to do to avoid this?

For the new line, I want to have Ctrl+Return, like it is in Skype.

```
procedure TForm1.StringGrid1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if (Key = VK_RETURN) and (ssCtrl in Shift) then // Ctrl+Return = New Line
  begin
    // TODO: Do NOT cancel edit mode
    // TODO: Insert #13#10 at current cursor position
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Use the code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20439948/62576), but reverse the logic to move cells down instead of up.

Comment: @KenWhite you misunderstood my question. I want to have a multi line text inside the cell, not a new row.

Comment: That's not what you asked. You asked about inserting a new line (which usually indicates row) in the grid. If you want to ask about multi-line text in a stringgrid, ask that question.

Comment: @KenWhite: what you linked to is not a duplicate, though. The OP is asking how to let users **edit** a cell's text as multi-line, not how to **display** multi-line text in a cell (the OP already knows how to do that).  The question you linked to is all about displaying text, not editing text.  And yes, there are ways to allow multi-line editing. What you suggested is one way, but not the only way.

Answer (score 3):

TStringGrid's built-in cell editor does not support multi-line text (it is a descendant of `TCustomMaskEdit`, which is single-line).  You will have to use a separate UI control, such as a `TMemo`, for editing multi-line text.  There are a few different ways to accomplish that:

1. disable the grid's built-in editor (remove the `goEditing` flag from the grid's `Options` property) and put a `TMemo` near the `TStringGrid`. When the user selects a cell (and optionally clicks a button/menu), assign its current text into the Memo.  If the user makes any changes (and optionally clicks another button/menu), assign the new text back to the cell.
2. a variation of the above: Design a separate `TForm` that has a `TMemo` and Save button on it.  When the user selects a cell (or pushes a button/menu), assign the cell's current text to the Form's Memo and then show the Form by calling its `ShowModal()` method.  If the user clicks the Save button, close the Form by setting its `ModalResult` property to `mrOk`.  If `ShowModal()` returns `mrOk`, assign the Memo's current text to the cell being edited and then `Invalidate()` the grid to trigger a repaint.  If `ShowModal()` returns anything else, do nothing.
3. a variation of the above: leave the grid's built-in editor enabled, and design a separate Form as above, but then configure the `TStringGrid` to trigger the Form automatically, without having to change the rest of your UI in *any way*.

   1. derive a new class from `TStringGrid` and have it override the virtual `GetEditStyle()` method to return `esEllipsis` (it returns `esSimple` by default), and override the virtual `CreateEditor()` method to return a new instance of a `TInplaceEditList`-derived class (it returns a `TInplaceEdit` object by default).  This will cause a cell to display a push button instead of an edit field when being edited.
   2. Have your `TInplaceEditList`-derived class own an instance of your Form, and then override the virtual `UpdateContents()` method to retrieve the current cell text and assign it to the Form's Memo, and override the virtual `DoEditButtonClick()` method to show the Form modally and respond to the return value of `ShowModal()` accordingly.